# Scrolling area in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I need recyclerview to scroll it's last item to the middle of itself. I mean that i need las element of recyclerview with LinearLayoutManager not to stop at the bottom of recyclerview but scroll to the middle of it.
Is it a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry but your question is unclear , Do you want when you reach the last item of RecyclerView, you are moved back to middle item of RecyclerView???

Comment: Can you add an empty footer View and manually set it's height to match half the height of your last item? That would achieve that effect of your list scrolling an extra distance of half the height of the last item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`RecyclerView.ItemDecoration`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html) to put an extra bottom-margin on the last item. It'll end up looking something like this:

```
public class TopMarginDecoration
        extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state) {

        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);

        if (position + 1 == parent.getAdapter().getItemCount()) {
            // get height of recyclerview
            // get height of child view
            // calculate required space to center the child view
            outRect.bottom += calculatedSpace;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use [`RecyclerView.addItemDecoration(…)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#addItemDecoration%28android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ItemDecoration%29) in your Activity or Fragment to tie this together.

Answer (score 0):

final LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

```
    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() == (llm.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() + 1)) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sholled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```